# Create a site web portfolio

Tags: windows-7, pdf

I need to generate a site web portfolio in PDF but I have issues with that.
I am trying to put all pages in one pdf without cuting the pages with A4 format.

I've searched this kind of tool without success and also I didn't find a trick to do that.

Comment: This seems rather like a "suggest something" thread, which isn't compatible with the format here... but I'll attempt an answer anyway.

Comment: What is a "site web portfolio"?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Kind of book of all pages of the website in one pdf.

Answer (score 1):

A portfolio of websites, for say a job application?

PDF is designed around paper, and therefore has a pages with a set size (Letter, A4, etc). So no, there isn't a way to do freeform sizes as you would on a website. Usually the way I see people do this is print/screencap only what would be seen when the page first loads (no scrolling).

Comment: Please check this pdf: http://pdfcast.org/pdf/asd-128 As we can see we have long web pages inside withtout cutting them in the a4 format.